# Get records that doesn't have connection

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables: `Products`, `ProductProperties`, `Properties`. I need to get all products, which do not have "Property B". Tables:

```
# Products          # Join table                  # Properties
+----+-----------+  +------------+-------------+  +-------------+---------------+
| id | name      |  | product_id | property_id |  | property_id | property_name |
+----+-----------+  +------------+-------------+  +-------------+---------------+
|  1 | Product 1 |  |          1 |           1 |  |           1 |   Propeprty A |
|  2 | Product 2 |  |          1 |           2 |  |           2 |   Propeprty B |
|  3 | Product 3 |  |          2 |           1 |  +-------------+---------------+
+----+-----------+  |          2 |           2 |
                    |          3 |           1 |
                    +------------+-------------+
```

In this particular case **I expect Product 3 to be returned**.

Is it possible to get all required products within a **single db query**? What the smallest query possible to achieve that?

**Edited**. Queries with sub-queries considered *bad*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want an OUTER JOIN and then a WHERE clause to bring back the non-matched Properties.  This is untested, but:

```
SELECT Products.* FROM 
Products RIGHT OUTER JOIN Join_Table 
  ON Products.ID = Join_Table.Product_ID
  AND Join_Table.Property_ID = 2
WHERE Products.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: That just plain 'ol won't work. Products.ID  will never be NULL - since that's the table your FROM clause is on and there's no RIGHT/FULL join.

Comment: Mark, you're right. Lester's answer have a typo: on line 5 it should be `Join_Table.Property_ID` in place of `Products.ID`.

Comment: Yeah I suppose i meant RIGHT JOIN of course, but I'd better step through it again before editing.

Comment: I edited to represent RIGHT join FYI.  But it looks like gmile's other interpretation of what I wrote worked too.   Thanks.

Comment: @LesterDove. In current version I guess, it will return rows with all nulls. You select Products.* where Products.Id is null

Comment: @LesterDove, can you please point me to a fine source where I could get a better understanding of how joins with multiple conditions (`... ON ... AND Join_Table.Property_ID = 2`) actually work?

Comment: Sure @g. Just as a WHERE clause can have multiple AND'ed conditions, so can the ON criteria of a JOIN. (At least this is true in MSSQL, I don't recall in MySQL.)  So, in this case we join on ProductID, but only where PropertyID = 2. However, this is an OUTER JOIN, so it returns all Product records and only 'matched' Property records, as per standard OUTER JOIN behavior.  That gives us a bunch of NULL Products (wherever they don't have PropertyID = 2.)  Finally, we use the WHERE clause of the query to filter for ONLY those records where Product is NULL.  This equals your target set.  (I hope.)

Comment: And here's a decent description of JOIN .. ON versus WHERE criteria.  There are many.   http://www.sqlteam.com/article/additional-criteria-in-the-join-clause

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Products P where not exists (select * from ProductProperties 
inner join Properties on ProductProperties .property_id = Properties property_id 
where P.product_id = ProductProperties.product_id and property_name = 'Propeprty B') -- *or whatever*
```

Comment: I guess it will not work. This query will return empty result set.

Comment: Thank you answer, but I was implying not to do sub-querying also.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get all products, which do not have "Property B"

Inverse the problem. Find the ones *with* `PropertyB`, then negate it.

Start with all `PropertyB` properties:

```
SELECT
     Property_Id
FROM Properties 
WHERE
     Property_Name = 'Property B'
```

Then, find `ProductId`s that *do* have those `Property_Id`s:

```
SELECT
     ProductId
FROM ProductProperties
JOIN (
     --1st query
     SELECT
         Property_Id
     FROM Properties 
     WHERE
         Property_Name = 'Property B'
) as PropertyB ON
    ProductProperties.Property_Id = PropertyB.Property_Id
```

Then, find all the `Product`s not in that set:

```
SELECT
    ProductId
FROM Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    --2nd query
    SELECT
        ProductId
    FROM ProductProperties
    JOIN (
        --1st query
        SELECT
            Property_Id
        FROM Properties 
        WHERE
            Property_Name = 'Property B'
    ) as PropertyB ON
       ProductProperties.Property_Id = PropertyB.Property_Id
) as ProductsWithPropertyB ON
     Products.ProductId = ProductsWithPropertyB.ProductId
WHERE
     ProductsWithPropertyB.ProductId IS NULL
```

then, you can simplify a bit:

```
SELECT
    ProductId
FROM Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ProductId
    FROM ProductProperties
    JOIN Properties ON
        ProductProperties.PropertyId = Properties.PropertyId
    WHERE
        Properties.Name = 'Property B'
) as ProductsWithPropertyB ON
     Products.ProductId = ProductsWithPropertyB.ProductId
WHERE
     ProductsWithPropertyB.ProductId IS NULL
```

Or, if you prefer `IN` clauses (the server likely doesn't care):

```
SELECT 
     ProductId 
FROM Products
WHERE
     ProductId NOT IN (
          SELECT ProductId FROM ProductProperties WHERE PropertyId IN (
              SELECT PropertyId FROM Properties WHERE PropertyName = 'Property B'
          )
     )
```

Comment: I did this initially, yet I'd like to avoid using sub-querying for efficiency.

Comment: You have 3 tables with the info. You aren't going to get more efficient than a 3 table join (or the equivalent IN clauses). What you want to likely avoid are *correlated* subqueries (which run once for each resultset row) - not subqueries at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mark. I now will definitly distinguish correlated sub-queries among others. Yet it seems that @LesterDove works fine for me

Comment: Thanks again for all your effort, Mark. Your answer does a great job in understanding things which helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Properties.property_name FROM Products
INNER JOIN ProductProperties ON Products.product_ID = ProductProperties.product_ID
INNER JOIN Properties ON ProductProperties.Property_ID = Properties.Property_ID
WHERE Properties.Property_ID <> 2
```

Comment: That will return the non-PropertyB properties for a Product that *has* a PropertyB.

Comment: You're right, I was typing way to fast. You should `LEFT OUTER JOIN Properties ON ProductProperties.Property_ID = Properties.Property_ID`

Answer (score -1):

Yes (corrected to remove subs),

```
    Select * from 
     Products pr
     left join jointable jt on pr.id = jt.product_id 
     join properties pr on jt.property_id = pr.property_id and pr.property_name = 'Property B'
 where jt.product_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you answer, but I was implying not to do sub-querying also.

Comment: I think your <> in the where clause needs to be =. Otherwise, you're returning products that *do* have a PropertyB.